# How can I print the iterations of the elements of a list just beneath them in a nice format

Tags: python, list

I am using Python 3 and I manage to have a nicely formatted print output when using few elements in a list and their index numbers + 1 like this:

> H  E  L  L  O
>
> 1  2  3  4  5

But it gets messed up as soon as it reaches index 11 or higher.

> H  E  L  L  O  M  Y  Q  U  E  S  T  I  O  N
>
> 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13

For this I am using `print('  '.join(list))` and for the index numbers I use

```
for i in range (1, len(list)+1):      
   print(i, end='  ')
```

I was wondering if there was an easier way to print the list elements with the index + 1 below them in a nice format.

Comment: Why can't you just display the last digit? So instead of 10 put 0, etc.

Comment: About how to print the index numbers: `print('  '.join([str(i+1) for i,j in enumerate(list)]))`.

Comment: It is required for me to display the whole number to make it "user friendly".

Comment: Thanks @KevinGuan it really helps, still have the trouble with the spacing for further numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
lst = [ch for ch in "HELLOMYQUESTION"]
print(' '.join([j + " " * (len(str(i+1)) - 1)  for i,j in enumerate(lst)]))
print(' '.join([str(i+1) for i,j in enumerate(lst)]))
```